# Add 'required' attribute to <select> element

Tags: html

I have a `<select>` dropdown in my HTML form. How do I add `required` attribute to my `<select>` element? I would like a pure HTML5 solution. I googled but I dont seem to find it.

[Here is my fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/46xF5/17/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first `<option>` needs to be empty. Otherwise, `required` will see it as a value filled.

**[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/46xF5/20/)**

```html
<select required>
    <option></option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I added `<option value=""></option>` but it is still taking it.

Comment: In your example, you haven't applied `required` on the `<select>`. See my example.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you must insert empty field in movie list.and add `required`

**HTML**

```
<form id="book_tickets">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Booking Details</legend>

        <p>
            <label for="movie_name">Choose Movie</label>
            <select id="movie_name" name="movie_name" required>
                <option></option>
                <option value="Movie 1">Movie 1</option>
                <option value="Movie 2">Movie 2</option>
                <option value="Movie 3">Movie 3</option>
            </select>
        </p>

        <p>
            <label for="theaters">Theaters</label>
            <input list="theaters" name="theaters" required>
                <datalist id="theaters">
                    <option value="Inox" />
                    <option value="E Square" />
                </datalist>
            </input>
        </p>

        <p>
            <label for="date">Select Date</label>
            <input type="date" name="date" id="date" required />
        </p>

        <p>
            <label for="email">Enter Email</label>
            <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="abc@gmail.com" required />
        </p>

        <p>
            <label for="tickets_quantity">Number of Tickets</label>
            <input type="number" min="1" max="10" name="tickets_quantity" id="tickets_quantity" required />
        </p>

        <p>
            <label>Total Price</label>
            <span id="total_price"></span>
        </p>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" id="book_tickets" value="Book Tickets" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

The required attribute on select element: [video demo](http://w3-video.com/Web_Technologies/HTML5/html5_attributes/select/html5_select_required_attribute.php)

select element HTML5 [here](http://w3-video.com/Web_Technologies/HTML5/html5_select_tag.php)

referring to the first option, check out the [placeholder label option demo](http://w3-video.com/Web_Technologies/HTML5/select/html5_select_tag_placeholder_label.php)